# Android Today's date

Tags: android

Hello I want to display current date. I trying do it like this:

```
calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+formattedDate);
```

But it don't display the date in my textView.

Is there a better way to display the same date? I want like this: Monday, April 22

Comment: Had you displayed the formattedDate in LogCat to verify that is correct? And another question, are you sure that the txtView has the right id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`.

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

should be

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMMM dddd");
```

Comment: Ok. I know but it don't display the date in my layout

Answer (score 1):

```
Date now = new Date();
String str = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(

        this, // Suppose you are in an activity or other Context subclass

        now.getTime(), // The time to display

        MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, // The resolution. This will display only minutes 
                          // (no "3 seconds ago"

        WEEK_IN_MILLIS, // The maximum resolution at which the time will switch 
                         // to default date instead of spans. This will not 
                         // display "3 weeks ago" but a full date instead

        0); // Eventual flags
```

Other values for MINUTE_IN_MILLIS and YEAR_IN_MILLIS include:

```
SECOND_IN_MILLIS
MINUTE_IN_MILLIS
HOUR_IN_MILLIS
DAY_IN_MILLIS
WEEK_IN_MILLIS
YEAR_IN_MILLIS
Any custom value in milliseconds
```

Then set text as

```
txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+now);
```